# Wordpress search form 2 input text field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a Wordpress site. I want to search with 2 input text field in one search form. One for searching title and one for custom-field.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to create a searchform.php file in your theme with the new field. It's best to create a child theme for any custom work.

Once you've modified the search form, you'll need to hook into the search query. I don't know off hand what filter you'll need to use, probably the pre_get_posts hook. There's some good documentation about how to use pre_get_posts on wp's codex.

Comment: Thank for you answer bro :). But I still didn't get what I want :(